# PayPal Payment Link Not Working

Tags: php, paypal

I've read through PayPal's URL Paramenters for generating a payment link. However I seem to be having an issue whilst redirecting the user. I am taken to PayPal's homepage as if I have redirected the user to https://www.paypal.com which I have not. I will leave my code below...

```
//Error Checking
//Min Payment & Max Payment
... if($payment_amount>10.00) { ...

//Redirect User for Payment
$paypal_email = $email;
$return_url = $sso_url."/myaccount/payments/success";
$cancel_url = $sso_url."/myaccount/payments/cancel";
$notify_url = $sso_url."/servlet/gateway/PayPal-IPN.Event.php";

$payment_url  ="cmd=_xclick&business=$paypal_email&currency_code=GBP&no_shipping=1&amount=$payment_amount&item_name=Service+Payment+My+Account&return=$return_url&cancel_url=$cancel_url";
$payment_url  = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?".rawurlencode(utf8_encode($payment_url));

header("Location: $payment_url");
exit();
```

Code runs with no errors, but then I'm redirected to the PayPal homepage, and I can't seem to find why?

> **Link that my script generates**
>
> https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd%3D_xclick%26business%3Dsales%40domain.com%26currency_code%3DGBP%26no_shipping%3D1%26amount%3D15.00%26invoice%3D001MyAccount%26item_name%3DMyAccount%26return%3D%2F%2Fid.mydomain.com%2Fmyaccount%2Fpayments%2F%3FPayPal_Response%3Dsuccess%26cancel_url%3D%2F%2Fid.mydomain.com%2Fmyaccount%2Fpayments%2F%3FPayPal_Response%3Dcancel

Comment: Have you echoed out your `$payment_url` that you send to `header("Location: $payment_url");` and inspected the value?

Comment: Yes, I've updated my answer with the echoed response

Comment: (1) I find it odd that you have `$payment_url  = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/...` (sandbox), but your output is `https://www.paypal.com/...` (without sandbox). (2) I have never seen a PayPal `GET` link unless it was a hosted button. Typically I have only used the URL Params when doing a `POST`. So I am not sure how PayPal does with custom `GET` payment links. Hopefully someone else comes along to help.

Comment: @Sean it's because I'm trying to get it to work after I posted this question. However I still get the same result whilst running in sandbox

Answer (score 0):

When I un-URL-encoded the string, it worked perfectly fine. Try not URL encoding it.

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=sales@domain.com&currency_code=GBP&no_shipping=1&amount=15.00&invoice=001MyAccount&item_name=MyAccount&return=//id.mydomain.com/myaccount/payments/?PayPal_Response=success&cancel_url=//id.mydomain.com/myaccount/payments/?PayPal_Response=cancel